# Make WPF text resize to fill the space

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i make the text from the buttons, textbox and textblock resize automatically when the window resizes? If i resize the window a lot the everything resizes but the font size not and it looks small.

Viewbox doesn't achieve what im looking for, i just want the text to fill the content as it does in Unity (for example) without changing the object size.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's not directly build-in but you can implement that behavior by binding the FontSize property of your text to the container size using a custom converter.

You can create a custom converter that calculates the font size needed to fill the space available in the container (ie. ActualWidth and ActualHeight minus Padding).

To get the estimated size of rendered text, you can use the **[FormattedText class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Media_FormattedText__ctor_System_String_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_System_Windows_FlowDirection_System_Windows_Media_Typeface_System_Double_System_Windows_Media_Brush_System_Double_)**.

Then, your algorithm in the converter can perform a few calculations using some modified binary search for example, to determine the best font size such that the rendered output fits in the container space.

Alternatively, you could create a converter to bind a scale transform on the text, based on its [desired size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.desiredsize?view=net-5.0) to make it fit in the container's actual size.